# User Agent Ignore Controller

Tags: codeigniter

I have set a error message where if is redirected to this login controller then shows this message below. Using the **user_agent** library which I have auto loaded.

```
if ($this->agent->referrer()) {
   $this->error['warning'] = '<i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>  No activity within' .' '.gmdate("H:i:s", config_item('sess_expiration')).' '. 'seconds; please log in again';
} else {
   $this->error['warning'] = "";
}
```

**Question:** I would like to know if possible to ignore message if redirected from my logout controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
if ($this->agent->referrer() && $this->agent->referrer() !== 'http://example.com/logout') {
    $this->error['warning'] = '<i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>  No activity within' .' '.gmdate("H:i:s", config_item('sess_expiration')).' '. 'seconds; please log in again';
} else {
    $this->error['warning'] = "";
}
```

This should work, it can be optimized a little but this give you the idea. The if statement should evaluate to true on all referrers except from ones that come from whatever the url is of your logout page.

Does this make sense?